# Error log for Android apps in Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I am desesperately looking for an error log in which I could find the conditions of Android apps crashes under Netbeans. Does anyone know where I can find one?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Netbeans Window -> Output -> ADB Log

You can also try in the console "ddms" or "adb logcat" depending on where those executables are installed on your system (SDK installation), or run them directly, if you have your environment setup correctly.

Comment: I already noticed this ADB log. But I only get in it messages related to the connection with the emulator and absolutely nothing about the reason why an application crashes.

Comment: do you select your emulator device? Is it configured to see all types of messages? Have you tried to use the console commands?

Comment: ddms does the job. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can better use standalone DDMS tool to see logs. The DDMS can be found in android tools. e.g.

C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat

Answer (score -1):

you must  Window => Output => ADB Log
 and better for you download eclipse. All examples in android doing in Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html